# How to avoid Method Overloading in Java to avoid duplicates?

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style

I have 2 method which performs 80% same work but differ in result processing. I am doing :

```
 private <T> T getResponse(final RestURI query, final Class<T> responseClass) throws IOException {
        T response = null;

        final RestResponse<Record> tempResponse = getResponseFromDataPath(query);

        if (isResponseOK(tempResponse, query)) {
            final CustomReader reader = createCustomReaderFromResponse(tempResponse);
            response = objectMapper.readValue(reader, responseClass);
                                                          ^
            // DIFFERENCE --------------------------------|
        }

        return response;
    }

    private <T> T getResponse(final RestURI query, final TypeReference valueTypeRef) throws IOException {
        T response = null;

        final RestResponse<Record> tempResponse = getResponseFromDataPath(query);

        if (isResponseOK(tempResponse, query)) {
            final CustomReader reader = createCustomReaderFromResponse(tempResponse);
            response = objectMapper.readValue(reader, valueTypeRef);
                                                          ^
            // DIFFERENCE --------------------------------|
        }

        return response;
    }
```

This looks like lot of duplicate. How do I make this such that I reduce the duplicates.

Comment: Pass all three parameters into a single constructor, and the simply pass `null` in the unused parameter. Check for `null` to distinguish inside the constructor.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal that's horrible design.

Comment: extract the duplicate code in a shared method

Comment: Honestly, it would be helpful if you somehow marked or explicitly repeated the *not common* parts. I had to re-read the code 5 times to figure where they are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `BiFunction` parameter that calls `objectMapper`:

```
private <T> T getResponse(final RestURI query, 
    final BiFunction<CustomReader, ObjectMapper, T> mapper) throws IOException {
    T response = null;

    final RestResponse<Record> tempResponse = getResponseFromDataPath(query);

    if (isResponseOK(tempResponse, query)) {
        final CustomReader reader = createCustomReaderFromResponse(tempResponse);
        response = mapper.apply(reader, objectMapper); 
    }

    return response;
}
```

And callers can choose how to call `objectMapper`:

```
getResponse(query, 
   (reader, objectMapper) -> objectMapper.readValue(reader, <valueTypeRef>);
```

Or:

```
getResponse(query, 
    (reader, objectMapper) -> objectMapper.readValue(reader, <class>);
```

Comment: The important thing to keep in mind: this is only a good idea when that method stays private. Would it be something that **external** code is using, then obviously do not want to expose such a level of detail. Nice answer though!

Comment: @GhostCat Agreed.

Comment: As `getResponse()` is a `private` method, the caller method can directly reference the `objectMapper` field in the lambda body : `getResponse(query, reader -> objectMapper.readValue(reader, valueTypeRef));`. So `Function<CustomReader, T>` is enough.   Which simplifies things in both sides.